# HTML <a> tag positioning & height

Tags: css, html

I was following [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/fancy-3d-button) tutorial to use a fancy button on my page.

Everything work except the height of the  tag, as you can see in the following image:

[image: Screen capture]

I changed only the colors, the code is the same in the tutorial!

Thank y'all in advance!

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Avanti</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
position: relative;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,76,126,1);
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(0,34,56,1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(0,34,56,1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(0,34,56,1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    margin: 25px auto;
width: 160px;
text-align: center;

-webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease;
-o-transition: all .1s ease;
transition: all .1s ease;
}

a:active {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,34,56,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,34,56,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,34,56,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
position: relative;
top: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some relevant coding demonstrating the issue.

Comment: cab u please post the code?

Comment: as I wrote, the code is the same as the one found in the tutorial linked. Anyway, I've edited the answer with the code..

Comment: The CSS code is correct, if you see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YH9QQ/, you will see that the button renders correctly. There is something else in your that changes the height. Check it with your browser's developer tools and you might find what it is that messes it up

Comment: I think that it inherits the height of the parent div, but how can I do to say "hey, do not inherit the height of the parent div"?

Comment: HTML elements do not inherit the size of the parent, unless you do something special to make that happen (such as, set `height:100%` explicitly). So, what other CSS do you have?

Comment: Can you link your project ? plz

Comment: I'm working on it in local..Anyway I solved my problem, I commented the line display:block and used the left:Npx to move it around where I needed. Not the best solution, but it's fine for me. Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this block of code:

```
left: 100px;
top: 150px;
```

in to your CSS of the a element
you can customize the numbers